# How to print lines between two occurrences of the same character?

Tags: string, bash, pattern-matching

I have very large text files of the form below:

```
>randomheader1 some info flag1
data
moredata
someextradata
>randomheader2 some info flag2
littledata
somedata
>randomheader3 some info flag1
one
two
three
four
>randomheader4 some info flag3
....
```

I want to get the output of the lines following the line containing `flag1` into another file, such as:

```
>randomheader1 some info flag1
data
moredata
someextradata
>randomheader3 some info flag1
one
two
three
four
```

I've been reading to find a solution, I've checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/9743264), however since the matching patterns I'm looking for are the same characters (namely `>`), it didn't work. I'm looking for a solution in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk '{if($0~/^>/){ if($0~/flag1/) {flag="Y"} else {flag=""}} }flag '
```

Demo:

```
$cat temp.txt 
>randomheader1 some info flag1
data
moredata
someextradata
>randomheader2 some info flag2
littledata
somedata
>randomheader3 some info flag1
one
two
three
four
>randomheader4 some info flag3
$awk '{if($0~/^>/){ if($0~/flag1/){flag="Y"} else {flag="" } }}flag ' temp.txt
>randomheader1 some info flag1
data
moredata
someextradata
>randomheader3 some info flag1
one
two
three
four
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data file doesn't contain any null character ('\0'), a solution in pure *bash* could be:

$ cat filter

```
#!/bin/bash

in_flag=
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
        \>*\ flag1) in_flag=t ;;
        \>*) in_flag= ;;
    esac
    [[ -n $in_flag ]] && echo "$line"
done
```

Run it as

```
./filter < datafile > outfile
```